# How does setState update a const variable? (In ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, web, constants, setstate, use-state

***From what I know***

A **const** variable cannot be changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does JavaScript mechanism behind react hooks work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895455/how-does-javascript-mechanism-behind-react-hooks-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about react-hooks.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Here, `const` is a guard against reassigning the value of the reference within the same scope.