# How do react hooks determine the component that they are for?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I noticed that when I was using react hooks, a child component's state change does not rerender a parent component that had no state change. This is seen by this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmx6nqr4o

Due to the lack of passing the component to the hook as an argument, or as a bind context, I had mistakenly thought that react hooks / state changes simply triggered an entire application rerender, like how mithril works, and what React's [Design Principles](https://reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html#scheduling) states:

> React walks the tree recursively and calls render functions of the whole updated tree during a single tick.

Instead, it seems that react hooks know which component they are associated to, and thus, the rendering engine knows to only update that single component, and never call `render` on anything else, opposing what React's Design Principles document said above.

1. How is the association between hook and component done?
2. How does this association make it so that react knows to only call `render` on components whose state changed, and not those without? (in the code sandbox, despite child's state changing, the parent element's `render` is never called)
3. How does this association still work when you abstract the usage of useState and setState into custom hook functions? (as the code sandbox does with the `setInterval` hook)

Seems the answers lie somewhere with this trail [resolveDispatcher](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fef40c061ec7db03b6b0faa7608788d625cf78db/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L16-L23), [ReactCurrentOwner](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fef40c061ec7db03b6b0faa7608788d625cf78db/packages/react/src/ReactCurrentOwner.js), [react-reconciler](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/fef40c061ec7db03b6b0faa7608788d625cf78db/packages/react-reconciler).

Comment: @Li357 if that was the only thing going on, then with https://codesandbox.io/s/kmx6nqr4o the parent's vdom would be different from the dom, so it would also be updated, but the parent component is never rerendered at all

Comment: It seems https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fef40c061ec7db03b6b0faa7608788d625cf78db/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L16-L23 is the answer, but no idea how that works, and how it answers the two questions posed

Comment: If an entire vdom rerender occurs due to any state change, then the parent's vdom would also differ (as it is the current time, just like the child). So this doesn't have anything to do with vdom, it has everything to do with component state association.

Comment: @RyanC definitely cross-over, however I think the way the question was posed was too broad, hence its closure. I've done my best for this question to isolate the question and problem to a specific example and solution.

Comment: I think the answers to that question also answer this more specific question.

Comment: @RyanC I've gone through the resources of both those two answers, neither explain the mechanism why the parent element in my example does not update when the child does. They do touch on fibers, but there is no clarity there.

Comment: I've removed the comment generated by flagging this as a possible duplicate and also provided an answer.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

First of all, if you are looking for a conceptual explanation of how hooks work and how they know what component instance they are tied to then see the following:

- [in depth article I found after writing this answer](https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba)
- [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components)
- [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729917/react-hooks-whats-happening-under-the-hood)
- [related blog post by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/)

The purpose of this question (if I understand the intent of the question correctly) is to get deeper into the actual implementation details of how React knows which component instance to re-render when state changes via a setter returned by the `useState` hook. Because this is going to delve into React implementation details, it is certain to gradually become less accurate as the React implementation evolves over time. When quoting portions of the React code, I will remove lines that I feel obfuscate the most relevant aspects for answering this question.

The first step in understanding how this works is to find the relevant code within React. I will focus on three main points:

- the code that executes the rendering logic for a component instance (i.e. for a function component, the code that executes the component's function)
- the `useState` code
- the code triggered by calling the setter returned by `useState`

**Part 1** How does React know the component instance that called `useState`?

One way to find the React code that executes the rendering logic is to throw an error from the render function. The following modification of the question's CodeSandbox provides an easy way to trigger that error:

[image: Edit React hooks parent vs child state]

This provides us with the following stack trace:

```
Uncaught Error: Error in child render
    at Child (index.js? [sm]:24)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15108)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:16925)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18498)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:347)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:397)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:23217)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22208)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22185)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:21878)
    at runRootCallback (react-dom.development.js:21554)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:11353)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:643)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:11305)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11349)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11338)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21677)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2359)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5979)
```

So first I will focus on `renderWithHooks`. This resides within [ReactFiberHooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L365). If you want to explore more of the path to this point, the key points higher in the stack trace are the [beginWork](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberBeginWork.js#L2632) and [updateFunctionComponent](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberBeginWork.js#L595) functions which are both in ReactFiberBeginWork.js.

Here is the most relevant code:

```
    currentlyRenderingFiber = workInProgress;
    nextCurrentHook = current !== null ? current.memoizedState : null;
    ReactCurrentDispatcher.current =
      nextCurrentHook === null
        ? HooksDispatcherOnMount
        : HooksDispatcherOnUpdate;
    let children = Component(props, refOrContext);
    currentlyRenderingFiber = null;
```

`currentlyRenderingFiber` represents the component instance being rendered. This is how React knows which component instance a `useState` call is related to. No matter how deeply into custom hooks you call `useState`, it will still occur within your component's rendering (happening in this line: `let children = Component(props, refOrContext);`), so React will still know that it is tied to the `currentlyRenderingFiber` set prior to the rendering.

After setting `currentlyRenderingFiber`, it also sets the current dispatcher. Notice that the dispatcher is different for the initial mount of a component (`HooksDispatcherOnMount`) vs. a re-render of the component (`HooksDispatcherOnUpdate`). We'll come back to this aspect in Part 2.

**Part 2** What happens in `useState`?

In [ReactHooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L77) we can find the following:

```
    export function useState<S>(initialState: (() => S) | S) {
      const dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
      return dispatcher.useState(initialState);
    }
```

This will get us to the `useState` function in [ReactFiberHooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1286). This is mapped differently for initial mount of a component vs. an update (i.e. re-render).

```
const HooksDispatcherOnMount: Dispatcher = {
  useReducer: mountReducer,
  useState: mountState,
};

const HooksDispatcherOnUpdate: Dispatcher = {
  useReducer: updateReducer,
  useState: updateState,
};

function mountState<S>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
): [S, Dispatch<BasicStateAction<S>>] {
  const hook = mountWorkInProgressHook();
  if (typeof initialState === 'function') {
    initialState = initialState();
  }
  hook.memoizedState = hook.baseState = initialState;
  const queue = (hook.queue = {
    last: null,
    dispatch: null,
    lastRenderedReducer: basicStateReducer,
    lastRenderedState: (initialState: any),
  });
  const dispatch: Dispatch<
    BasicStateAction<S>,
  > = (queue.dispatch = (dispatchAction.bind(
    null,
    // Flow doesn't know this is non-null, but we do.
    ((currentlyRenderingFiber: any): Fiber),
    queue,
  ): any));
  return [hook.memoizedState, dispatch];
}

function updateState<S>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
): [S, Dispatch<BasicStateAction<S>>] {
  return updateReducer(basicStateReducer, (initialState: any));
}
```

The important part to notice in the `mountState` code above is the `dispatch` variable. That variable is the setter for your state and gets returned from `mountState` at the end: `return [hook.memoizedState, dispatch];`. `dispatch` is just the `dispatchAction` function (also in ReactFiberHooks.js) with some arguments bound to it including `currentlyRenderingFiber` and `queue`. We'll look at how these come into play in Part 3, but notice that `queue.dispatch` points at this same `dispatch` function.

`useState` delegates to `updateReducer` (also in [ReactFiberHooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L658)) for the update (re-render) case. I'm intentionally leaving out many of the details of `updateReducer` below except to see how it handles returning the same setter as the initial call.

```
    function updateReducer<S, I, A>(
      reducer: (S, A) => S,
      initialArg: I,
      init?: I => S,
    ): [S, Dispatch<A>] {
      const hook = updateWorkInProgressHook();
      const queue = hook.queue;
      const dispatch: Dispatch<A> = (queue.dispatch: any);
      return [hook.memoizedState, dispatch];
    }
```

You can see above that `queue.dispatch` is used to return the same setter on re-render.

**Part 3** What happens when you call the setter returned by `useState`?

Here is the signature for [dispatchAction](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.9.0/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L658):

```
function dispatchAction<A>(fiber: Fiber, queue: UpdateQueue<A>, action: A)
```

Your new state value will be the `action`. The `fiber` and work `queue` will be passed automatically due to the `bind` call in `mountState`. The `fiber` (the same object saved earlier as `currentlyRenderingFiber` which represents the component instance) will point at the same component instance that called `useState` allowing React to queue up the re-rendering of that specific component when you give it a new state value.

Some additional resources for understanding the React Fiber Reconciler and what fibers are:

- Fiber Reconciler portion of https://reactjs.org/docs/codebase-overview.html
- https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture
- https://blog.ag-grid.com/index.php/2018/11/29/inside-fiber-in-depth-overview-of-the-new-reconciliation-algorithm-in-react/

Comment: This is great information!

Would you be able to elaborate on "The fiber will point at the same component instance that called useState allowing React to queue up the re-rendering of that specific component when you give it a new state value.", as I couldn't find that much documentation about Fibers on the react website. Or perhaps the documentation on the website is incorrect. I've updated the question to elaborate on what the documentation states, and split question 1 into Q1 and Q2, to ensure that Q2 can be answered succinctly. You've answered Q1 and Q3 very well so far!

Comment: I've added some additional resources at the end that explain the fiber architecture and tried to clarify my statement a little.