# React useState - setValue rerenders the component even though the value is the same

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useState` hook in a custom hook.

I'm calling the `setValue` function that is returned from the `useState` twice:

1) After an onChange event

2) After the component was notified of a change from the server.

The flow of events is:

- onChange event (in the component) triggers `setValue` = **rerender**
- I'm using a `useEffect` (**=after rerender**) hook to update the server of the change - API function is called to update the server
- I have a custom service which receives the server's response and notifies the component
- When notified the component calls `setValue` again but in this case, the value is the same so no need to rerender.

My problem is the component gets rerendered after it was notified of the changes even though the value received is the same.

My code:

**Gain Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useDSPParamUpdate } from '../../../Hooks/useDSPParamUpdate';
import { ControlParamProps } from '../..';

const Gain = (props: ControlParamProps) => {

  let min: number = 0;
  let max: number = 0;


  const { paramId, controlId } = props;
  const { param, value, setValue } = useDSPParamUpdate({ controlId, paramId })

  if (param && param.range && param.range.length >= 2) {
    min = param.range[0];
    max = param.range[1];
  }

  /*calls the setValue from the hook*/
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setValue(newValue);
  }


  return (
    <div className="gain">
      {max}
      <input className="dsp-action range-vertical" type="range"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange} />
      {min}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Gain;
```

**useDSPParamUpdate - custom hook**

```
    import * as React from 'react';
        import { ControlParamProps } from '../dsp';
        import { dspService } from '../../core/services/dsp.service';

        export function useDSPParamUpdate(props: ControlParamProps) {

            const initValue = ...
            const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initValue);

            function updateDevice() {
                // calls some API func to update the server (sends the value)
            }

            // subscribes to server changes
            React.useEffect(() => {
                    // subscribrs to server notifications
                    let unsubscribe = dspService.subscribe((newVal) => setValue(newVal));
                return () => {
                    unsubscribe();
                };
            }, []);


            // sends data to the server after update
            React.useEffect(() => {
                updateDevice();
            }, [value]);

            return { param, value, setValue };
        }
```

Comment: There are optimizations that avoid re-rendering in some cases when the same value is passed to a state setter, but there is no guarantee that it won't re-render.  For more details, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715188/react-hook-rendering-an-extra-time/54716601#54716601

Answer (score 1):

Typically it's not an issue if `render()` is called extra time.

But if you want you may guard calling `setValue()` by checking if value is the same

```
let unsubscribe = dspService.subscribe(
    (newVal) => 
        newVal !== value && setValue(newVal)
);
```

Maybe slightly verboose way but it's the same approach as typically used in `componentDidUpdate`

Note that `useState` does not provide any logic like `shouldComponentUpdate` has. So if you want to make it in more declarative way you have to refactor your component to be class-based accessor of `PureComponent`.

Comment: I tried this but when I debugged it I saw the `value` always had the initial value...What do you mean by "Typically it's not an issue if render() is called extra time."? From what I know extra rendering is a performance issue...

Comment: unfortunately I cannot find an article where it's measured. But under the hood `render()` does not make operations on DOM so it should be really fast(until you don't have complex math here). And since DOM is updated only if there is difference between "real DOM vs virtual DOM" I strongly believe you don't need to care about extra `render()` calls.

Comment: As for "`value` always has inital value" it's really weird since you finally output it so you should mention already if it was not ever changed

Comment: It is weird..I think it is a bug...Thanks anyway