# React Hooks: useEffect, useReducer, createContext and localStorage; TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect, use-context, use-reducer

I am using local storage in my Map app for some persistent storage; also using React.createContext coupled with useReducer to share and update state amongst components.

State in local storage, and in the app when consoled are updating and present, i.e. hash-generated id, paths from Cloudinary for images.

But when I click on the map to add a marker i get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'markers' of undefined

That is strange because of what I see in the console, and in local-storage.

My thinking is I have wired things incorrectly.

My UserContext component:

```
var initialState = {
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg',
  id: null,
  isRoutingVisible: false,
  removeRoutingMachine: false,
  isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: true,
  markers: [],
  currentMap: {}
};

var UserContext = React.createContext();

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  function userReducer(state, { type, payload }) {

    switch (type) {
      case 'setUserId': {
        return { ...state, ...{ id: payload.id } };
        }

      case 'setAvatar': {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...{ avatar: payload.avatar }
        };
      }

      case 'setIsRoutingVisible': {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...{ isRoutingVisible: payload.isRoutingVisible }
        };
      }

      case 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse': {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...{
            isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: payload.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo
          }
        };
       
      }

      case 'addMarker': {
        user.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo
          ? {
              ...state,
              markers: user.markers.concat(payload.marker)
            }
          : null;
        break;
      }
   
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${type}`);
      }
    }
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getLocalStorage('user', initialState));
  var [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, user);

  const [isAvatarUploading, setIsAvatarUploading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('user', state);
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state', state);
    if (state.markers.length === 2) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse',
        payload: { isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: false }
      });
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(state.markers)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state', state);

    if (state.id) {
      getUserAvatar()
        .then(userAvatar => {
          console.log('userAvatar ', userAvatar);
          setIsAvatarUploading(false);
          dispatch({
            type: 'setAvatar',
            payload: { avatar: userAvatar }
          });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('error thrown from getUserAvatar', err));
    } else {
      console.log('No user yet!');
    }
  }, [state.id]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userId: state.id,

        userAvatar: state.avatar,

        dispatch: dispatch,

        isAvatarUploading: state.isAvatarUploading,

        userImages: state.images,

        userMarkers: state.markers,

        userMap: state.currentMap,

        removeRoutingMachine: state.removeRoutingMachine,

        isRoutingVisibile: state.isRoutingVisible
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContext;

export { UserProvider };
```

I thought I needed to have a custom hook, to use to pass the old state and use it to watch changes and update it.

```
  var newUserState = initialState => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    var setter = useCallback(() => setState(state => !state), [setState]);
    return [state, setter];
  };


  var [newUserState, setter] = newUserState(state)
```

Any help would be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your `addMarker` case, you probably want to access the local `state` variable rather than the global `user`.

Also, from what I understood of [this other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892403/usereducer-action-dispatched-twice#answer-54894698) you'd rather define your reducer outside of your component, because React will trigger some unwanted update when you redefine the reducer fucntion.

Whether any of these will solve your issue, I can't say...