# Input value is getting printed double everytime for onChange Event - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm just trying useReducer on react. What ever I type, the values are geting printed double and also twice, as shown in below image.
[image: consoleImage]

I don't understand why. Below is my code .

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import "./sign.scss";

const SignIn = () => {

    const handleCredentials = (state: SignInCredentialsInit, action: { type: string, payload: string }) => {
        if (action.type === 'EMAIL') {
            console.log(action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                email: state.email + action.payload
            }
        }
        if (action.type === 'PASSWORD') {
            return {
                ...state,
                password: state.password + action.payload
            }
        }
    }

    const [credentials, updateCredential] = useReducer(handleCredentials, {
        email: "", password: ""
    });

    return (
        <section>
            <div className="signInBox">
                <p className="signInText">SIGN IN</p>
                <form>
                    <div className="inputFlex">
                        <input
                            className="inputBox"
                            type="email" required
                            value={credentials.email}
                            onChange={e => updateCredential({ type: 'EMAIL', payload: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <input className="inputBox" type="password" required />
                        <button ></button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default SignIn;
```

Also getting a warning on useReducer as:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer:
> ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?:
> undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(state: SignInCredentialsInit, action: {    type: string;    payload: string;}) => { email: string; password: string | null; } | { password: string; email: string | null; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: SignInCredentialsInit, action: { type: string; payload: string; }) => { email: string; password: string | null; } | { password: string; email: string | null; } | undefined, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ email: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.t

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useReducer Action dispatched twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892403/usereducer-action-dispatched-twice)

Comment: I believe the issue is concatenating `email: state.email + action.payload` and `password: state.password + action.payload` the current value to the action payload.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be better to move this "reducer Handler" to a separate file.
And you should remove the add operation to the previous value from your expression. But I generally recommend you not to use Reducer for these purposes.

If we are talking specifically about double output to the console - then you should read the  documentation.
https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

[web log in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAYKB.png)

```
if (action.type === 'EMAIL') {
    console.log(action.payload);
    return {
        ...state,
        email: action.payload // deleted: **state.email**
    }
}
if (action.type === 'PASSWORD') {
    return {
        ...state,
        password: action.payload // deleted: **state.password**
    }
}
```