# How to force an update for a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux and want to find out how `useSelector` updates a component, because the component doesn't have its own state.

I understand that `useSelector()` subscribes the component to the store, and when the store is updated, the component also updates.

Class components have `this.forceUpdate()`, but functional components don't have it.

How does one force-update a functional component?

Comment: If useSelector didn't update the component you probably mutated the state in the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply do this**

Add a dummy state that you can change to reliably initiate a re-render.

```
const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false);

...
//And whenever you want to re-render, you can do this
setRerender(!rerender);
```

And this will re-render the component, since components always re-render on state change

Answer (score 1):

The `react-redux` package relies on the rendering engine of `react`/`react-dom` to trigger the re-render of a given component that uses the `useSelector` hook.

If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/0bcaec47338e26c5a43f8dbc2593b5d84e312281/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L15) of `useSelector` you can notice the use of `useReducer`:

```js
const [, forceRender] = useReducer((s) => s + 1, 0)
```

As the name (`forceRender`) implies, redux uses this to trigger a re-render by react.

*With `v8` of `react-redux` the implementation of this mechanism changes but still relies on react-hooks for the re-render.*

---

If you are curious how React handles re-renders, take a look at [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980190/11641932). It provides a great entry on the implementation details of how react-hooks are associated with the calling component.

I don't repeat Ryan here, but **to sum it up**:

The renderer keeps a reference to the component that is currently rendered. All hooks being executed during this render (no matter how deeply nested in custom-hooks they are) ultimately belong to this component.
*So, the `useReducer` is associated with the component within which you called `useSelector`.*

The dispatch function of `useReducer` triggers a re-render of this component (React either calls the `render()` method of a class-component or executes the function body of a functional component).

---

If you are curious how `react-redux` determines when it should force this re-render (by utilizing `useReducer`), take another look at the [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/0bcaec47338e26c5a43f8dbc2593b5d84e312281/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L92) of `useSelector`.

Redux uses the subscriber-pattern to get notified of updates to the state. If the root-state of redux is updated the following things happen:

1. `useSelector` hooks in your application re-run their selector function
2. This re-selected state is compared to the previously selected state (by default via `===` comparison). *The second argument to `useSelector` can be a comparison function to change this behavior*
3. If the re-selected state differs from the previously selected state, a re-render is triggered via the `useReducer` hook.

The subscriber pattern is very react-like but potentially helps save many re-renders. Calling several `useSelector` hooks is cheap when compared with re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on other answers, to keep your code clean you can create a dummy state and then set it in your own forceUpdate function:

```
    const [helper, setHelper] = useState(false);
    function forceUpdate(){
        setHelper(!helper);
    }
```

Now you can just call `forceUpdate()` in the rest of your code:

```
<div onClick={() => forceUpdate()} />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to mention that you don't need to do a force update when you use useSelector hook. Rerender will happen automatically whenever the selected state value will be updated.

But if you need to force update the functional component you can use this approach.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

//create your forceUpdate hook
function useForceUpdate(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
    return () => setValue(value => ++value); // update the state to force render
}

function MyComponent() {
    // call your hook here
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

    return (
        <div>
            {/*Clicking on the button will force to re-render like force update does */}
            <button onClick={forceUpdate}>
                Click to re-render
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I highly recommend avoiding the use of this hack, in 99% of issues you can resolve them without force update. But in any case, it's good to know that there is such a possibility in the functional component exists too.

Comment: yes, i know that useSelector update component, but i want to know, how it works

Comment: When an action is dispatched to the Redux store, useSelector() only forces a re-render if the selector result appears to be different than the last result.
More info about what happens under the hood you can find here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you:

In a Class Component you could pass a property like the one below...

```
<Element onSomethingHappen={
   ()=>{
   if(shouldComponentUpdate())
      this.forceUpdate();
}}/>
```

In the function component you can call the updater like this one:

```
function FunctionComponent(props){
    //When you need it you can update like this one...
    props.onSomethingHappen(); 
    // Here you are ;) let me know if this helps you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers so far are acceptable and there is another option, Using `key` prop like the following:

```js
const TheComponentToBeRerendered = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);

  const forceUpdate = () => {
    setKey(s => s + 1);
  };

  return (
    <TheFirstWrapperEvenAFragment
      key={`_a_key_for_force_update_${key}`}
    >
      ~ ~ ~
    </TheFirstWrapperEvenAFragment>
  );
};
```

The `key` prop does exist in all components and by changing it, a force update would be guaranteed. So here, by calling the `forceUpdate` function the force update will have happened.