# how we are able to assign value to const variable with useState setvalue method in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have the following code :

```
function Usestatedemo() {
  const abc = useState(5);

  const count = abc[0];
  const setcount = abc[1];
  const changeit = () => {
    count = count + 1; // error here in setting value to count
    setcount(count + 1); // no error here
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Usestatedemo
      <button onClick={changeit}>click</button>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

While i am not able to change the value of count directly ,but can change through setcount method. Why this so.

Comment: `Usestatedemo` is called multiple times, const variables never really change

Comment: what i want to ask is how value is passed to count through setcount() that even const variable is able to receive new value

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729917/react-hooks-whats-happening-under-the-hood

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setCount`, you are not changing the local const `count` at all. You are just asking react to render your component again. React updates its internal state to store the new value. This internal state is not a `const` and so can be changed. Then react renders, and your component executes again.

When your code runs you make a brand new local const named `count`. It may have the same name as the previous one, but it's a completely new variable. It is not restricted to having the same value as the old one. `useState` returns a snapshot of react's internal state (ie, the new value you asked to set the state to) and you assign the new value to your new `count` variable.

Comment: Great explanation - UV.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments - consts are never changed here.

`Usestatedemo` is called multiple times, and `useState` returns a new value every time.

Changing state makes react rerender the component with new values

```js
let cache = undefined;

function Usestatedemo() {
  const abc = useState(5);

  const count = abc[0];
  const setcount = abc[1];
  const changeit = () => {
    setcount(count + 1);
  };
  // I replaced click and return with this
  setTimeout(changeit, 1000);
  console.log("count is", count);
}

Usestatedemo();

// use state implementation
// it's much more complicated in reality
function useState(initialValue) {
  if (cache === undefined) {
    cache = initialValue;
  }
  return [
    cache,
    (newValue) => {
      if (cache !== newValue) {
        cache = newValue;
        Usestatedemo();
      }
    },
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course that's correct, because you're not updating the reference of the object itself, you are updating either the value in the index 0, if you deconstruct it as an array; or a property name in the case you deconstruct it as an object (useful in custom hooks).

In your example `abc` is the const, but the value it holds is this:

```js
const abc = [myNumber: number, setMyNumber: (abc:number) => void]
```

When you try to update `abc` directly:

```js
abc = 10
```

You're trying to change the reference of the object itself to something completely different, and that's a no-no.

But, when you use the `setAbc`, what it does is update the index 0 of your const, not the const itself.

I'd suggest deconstructing the `useState` hook, so you check more clearly what is actually happening.

This is what I mean with the deconstruction:

```js
const [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState(0)
```